# What is Difference between HashMap and ArrayMap and which one is faster

Tags: java, android

ArrayMap is new in android and in a video of youtube an android developer telling that it is better than HashMap but i am confused

Comment: access in `HashMap` is faster beacuse of search by hash

Comment: From docs of `Arraymap` : `ArrayMap is a generic key->value mapping data structure that is designed to be more memory efficient than a traditional HashMap`

Comment: according to video ArrayMap is faster for limited number of element

Comment: Ignore all of this ridiculous advice from Google. Use `HashMap`.

Comment: *"and which one is faster"*: JavaDoc: "It is generally slower than a traditional HashMap" So, how about reading the JavaDoc first and then ask us about unclear parts?

Comment: I think you should go through this video then comment here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORgucLTtTDI

Comment: Those videos tell you to avoid enums, to avoid iterators and to avoid hashmaps. It's all nonsense, even for android. Josh Bloch tweeted a criticism of those videos, and I know who I believe.

Comment: I took a look at the source, ArrayMap is O(log N) access time (it does binary search). The claim that its more memory efficient is highly use-case dependent. Taking the stance that if you're hard pressed for memory you will likely have many items in the map where (log N) will no longer be neglibly small I'd say avoid ArrayMap unless you have *many small maps*. If you have large or few maps, use HashMap. HashMap is extremely efficient for access time (its *very* hard to beat, I looked at multiple open-source alternatives claiming to be *better*. They were *all* slower).